# What is this coming from my window?

Tags: windows, window-frame

[image: window]What is this coming from the window? Not water it's like oil but can't feel anything. Window next to it has it too. No smell, no texture, doesn't rub off, and not coming from the roof

Comment: Concrete block house in Florida USA? What is the outside temp there right now?

Comment: silicone from window seals

Comment: Need more info. Is the house new to you, i.e. did this just appear one day out of the blue etc? What makes you think it's not water? Water could be picking something up from the wall surface to feel 'oily'.

Comment: looks like it has something to do with the light gray material that is smeared on the blocks